Task :react-native-firebase_auth:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
 Task :react-native-firebase_auth:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
C:\crazyhorese\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\auth\android\src\main\java\io\invertase\firebase\auth\ReactNativeFirebaseAuthModule.java:1621: error: pattern matching in instanceof is not supported in -source 11
                    if (exception instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException collEx) {
                                                                                ^
  (use -source 16 or higher to enable pattern matching in instanceof)
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-firebase_auth:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

this error started occuring when i added react-native-firebase/storage to my project
before this everything is working finely .I am using java version 17 i have tried deleting nodemodules build folders and cleaning the cache of the project updating the firebase version nothing works now !!
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^21.2.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^21.2.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^21.2.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^21.2.0",

java -version
java version "17.0.12" 2024-07-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.12+8-LTS-286)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.12+8-LTS-286, mixed mode, sharing)

I want to  add react-native-firebase/storage
